# How to open .cs file using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, jpeg, image-compression

I am working  on compressing an image using *compressive sensing*.

I downloaded the [code](https://sites.google.com/site/eiexyuan/csvsjpeg?fbclid=IwAR1JzuX2PNqzNJuKe1xQx2wyoPg7QMal441c9p5fnQ3JVr5jcIZFc_0uho8). I ran the `demo_firstTry.m`, `demo_GAPTV.m` and `demo_read_CSfile_and_Reconstruct.m` functions, they worked well.
The problem is that I need the compressed vector, it is saved as `.cs` file in the path written on the function,
I don't know how to open this file to get the compressed image vector ?

Comment: It would be better to ask the author of the code that what is the format of the .cs file and how it should be opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATLAB's inbuilt function `cv.imread` as below:

```
img = cv.imread(filename)
img = cv.imread(filename, 'OptionName',optionValue, ...)
```

This should solve the query.

Comment: i tried this function and this error appeared ''Undefined variable "cv" or class
"cv.imread"., i use Matlab 2018a